# Where can I find a list of all the possible arguments of a wxPython function?

Tags: python, arguments, styles, wxpython, frame

I am using the library wxPython and I find it really hard to find all the possible arguments of its built in functions (I can easily find the parameters in the documentation, but not the arguments). In particular i would like to know what I can specify in the "style" parameter when I initialize a frame:

```
class main_window(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, size=(x, y), style=???????, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: pycharm is great for this https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm, you can jump directly to the source code which usually has comments detailing the arguments

Comment: Thanks, I already use PyCharm luckilly, could you please guide me through the process of opening the source code of a specific library? I am pretty new to both PyCharm and programming

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Frame.html#styles-window-styles

Comment: ctrl-b will jump you to the source and is usually the quickest way to see what arguments are accepted, as mentioned above the docs are also a good resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a neat little styles and event hunter script that was released a few years ago that you can use:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/07/25/wxpython-windows-styles-and-events-hunter/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-dev/fBlHe7ytTvQ

There's also a thread on the wxPython Google group that mentions that this utility is now a part of the wxPython demo:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/c8a-I8Q7eFY

Of course, the wxPython documentation will also give you this information too, once you figure out how to navigate it:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Frame.html#styles-window-styles